# Modify Touch Id Plugin Default Authentication Popup (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, touch-id

I used touch Id plugin in my IOS Application by following below URL:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/touchid_authentication_with_worklight?lang=en

I implemented plugin properly and it is working. I want to change in the plugin code such that the Touch ID default popup should be removed but the touch authentication should work.
Please suggest on this.

Comment: You can't customise touch Id popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are attempting to subvert the way TouchID works, and that is a big no-no. You should keep the TouchID UI as it is since that is part of the Touch ID experience Apple decided on. And I don't think you can change that anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to add an extra label in popup of "enter password" at the start when popup opens . As currently enter password comes when user gives incorrect fingerprint authentication.

Comment: The UI is controlled by Apple AFAIK.